# Firebase list is not updating in set state

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The Flutter setState function not updating the list after retrieving from Firebase.

I am trying to develop a Flutter app. I am not getting updating the list in setState() function. The list is successfully retrieving from firebase. I have written the firebase connections in `Services.dart` file.

But my method `_getList()` is not getting the value in `main.dart` file.

**main.dart**

```
    class DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {

    List<Product> list;

        @override
    void initState() {
        _checkUser();  // for getting user id from firebase auth
    }

        @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return new Scaffold(
                body: new Container(
                    child:new Text("data");
                );
            )
    }

    void _checkUser(){
        debugPrint("Entering in _checkUser");
        this.firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((firebaseUser)async{
            _getList(firebaseUser.uid);
        });
    }


    void _getList(String id)
    debugPrint("Entering in _getList");
        Services.retrieveItems(firestore, uid).then((onValue){
                setState(() {
                    list=onValue;
                        debugPrint("items list:"+onValue.length.toString());
                        debugPrint("items list:"+listCart.length.toString());
                });
        });
        }
    }
```

**Services.dart**

```
    static Future<List> retrieveItems(Firestore firestore, String userId) async {
        List<Product> items = new List<Product>();
        try {
        firestore.collection("Items").document(userId)
        .collection("ItemsMain").snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot)  {
            List docList = snapshot.documents;
            items = snapshot.documents.map((documentSnapshot) => Product.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data)).toList();
            debugPrint("items:"+items.length.toString());
            //return items;
        });
        } on Exception catch (e) {
        print (e.toString());
        }

        debugPrint("items 2:"+items.length.toString());
        return items;
    }
```

**Expected results:**

Entering in _checkUser

Entering in _getList

items:6

items 2:6

items list:6

items list:6

**Actual results:**

Entering in _checkUser

Entering in _getList

items list:0

items list:0

items 2:0

items:6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the items before they are loaded. The simplest way to fix this is to use `await` in `retrieveItems` to wait for the data to be loaded from Firestore:

```
static Future<List> retrieveItems(Firestore firestore, String userId) async {
    List<Product> items = new List<Product>();
    var snapshot = await firestore.collection("Items").document(userId)
                                  .collection("ItemsMain").getDocuments()
    List docList = snapshot.documents;
    items = snapshot.documents.map((documentSnapshot) => Product.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data)).toList();
    debugPrint("items:"+items.length.toString());

    return items;
}
```

You'll note that I:

- Call `get()` instead of `listen()`. Since `listen()` starts actively monitoring the collection, it is impossible to say when it is "done". A `get()` on the other hand, returns the documents once, and is then done.
- Removed the exception handling, just to make the code a bit more readable. But I also recommend only adding exception handlers in functional code like this if you're actually handling the exception. Leave "log and continue" handlers for higher-level code, such as your main method.